# iPod and iPhone iMessage inquiry

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, messages

Okay, so my iPhone and iPod are both connected therefore the iMessages that I receive on my iPhone are also sent to my iPod, but earlier by mistake I disconnected my iPod through my iPhone settings. Couple hours pass by and I just connected them again but I just wanted to know will the iMessages I received earlier ever go through to my iPod or will it only receive the iMessages from the time I re-connected?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, your iPod will load the previous messages. That's from my experience...

Comment: Do you know how long that normally takes?

Comment: @user93190 10 seconds...

Comment: It's been an half an hour & nothing but the most recent iMessages popped up on my iPod. Does that mean I should give up on receiving those old messages?

Comment: @user93190 Hmm, probably.. As I said, it takes just a few seconds for me to load the older messages..